# how Subtract The max and min value with group by data increase or decrease in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need calculate the  different in temperature in sql server automatically so its calculate max point - min point - can happen many time just dedect it if temperature increase and start decrease again .i want to loop over and defect the decrease and sum it every time it decrease only

For Example :

i have table like that

```
37
36
35
34
33---> here it give me 37-34 and output
34
35
36
37
38
37
36
35
34---> here it give me 38-34
```

Comment: Do you have other columns, such as a date column, in the table, which can be used for sorting the data?

Comment: Without an order by in your query, there is no guarantee that SQL Server will return the results in any particular order. The order will depend on the execution plan that is chosen my the optimizer at query execution time.

Comment: What if the data had stopped at 37? Should the difference have been calculated as 37-34 or ignored because it did not start decreasing?

Comment: yes i have date time column but it can increase and decrease many time/day thats why i want to make report that defect the large decrease amount or increase , thanks for your help ..

Comment: it should only calculate between any max and min  when reach the max point and start decrease - the sampling point is the highest point before it start decrease

Comment: Tried to get max,min and group by hour , but its not accurate , any good algorithm to follow ?